# Solving vector differential equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I want to solve the following vector-differential equation for $\phi$ in terms of the rest of the variables.

$\phi = -\tau \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{F}+(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{s})\cdot\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}\phi$.

I am new to vector calculus, so I am not sure how to proceed. I tried taking $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}$ on both sides of the equation but couldn't proceed.

Comment: Are $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{s}$ fixed vector fields?

Comment: Yes they are fixed.

Comment: What is $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}$? Is $\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}\phi$ the projection along $\mathbf{v}$ of $\nabla\phi$?